# Window object and properties persistance

Tags: javascript

I know the Window object is the "master" object of the browser (tab) to which everything is appended - core methods, globally declared variables, functions, even the DOM. It is above everything.

When I go to a different page in the same browser window (tab) I suppose the window object remains the same (only the dom changes), because the history and other stuff is accessible. Why I don't quite grasp is why the global variables that are attached to the window object (even using `window.myvariable`) don't persist.

To me the only possible explanation is because it is made this way. If so what happens, do the "non core" window elements (methods and variables that were set by the code) get erased; is every new page visit a new instance of the window object (sounds the most obvious way to me) or ...?

I can't find any useful info on this matter, usually people only know that you can't pass variables between pages (except cookies, web storage, window title), but why/how (the mechanics, not reasons) this happens are hard to come by. Thanks.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong, every tab has its own `window` object. Also, above `window` there's browser itself, where for example `history` and many other objects are basicly coming from.

Comment: Edited so it mentions tabs. I quoted the "master" word to indicate that it is not a true master, but I see your point, it is not above everything. But in the same tab it should still be the master object to what everything on the page is appended and which all the webpage interaction with the browser goes through. Hence "master".

Comment: My point was actually "`every tab has its own window object`", the browser is there just to point, where `window` gets a part of its objects. Also you can pass variables (or at least values) to other windows, this is districted only by security features. If you open a page from the same domain in a new tab/window using JS, you can also interact with its window object. There's PostMessage for interacting with even cross-domain iframes etc.

Comment: I'm not following you well here. By tab you mean an actual browser tab (the open with ctrl+T kind), or are you reffering to a webpage as in every visit to a webpage makes a new instance of the window object of which the "prototype" (in JS terms) holds the methods, pointers etc to the browser. I would like a simplified info on the mechanics. Eg. i'm on google.com, then I go to yahoo.com. Do the (if any) global variables that were set on google.com somehow reset (clear) or does the browser make a new window instance for yahoo.com. So is the window cleaned or do we install a new one :)

Answer (score 3):

All the global JavaScript variables, functions & objects automatically become member of the window object and they are persisted as long as the the new page is not loaded/visited in the same browser window (tab).

Whenever new page is loaded or we redirect to new page within same tab then scope of these functions and variables from previous document ends and they are removed from the window object. And globally declared variables and functions for newly loaded document (from scripts associated with document) gets attached to the window object

Answer (score 2):

Every tab in your browser is independent window object and has its own set of global variables and thus your assumption of sharing window object is not correct. Your javascript is not and should not be allowed to SEE between tabs. If that was possible then imagine one webpage you open sniffing data and other information between tabs. Your tabs are not allowed to do your browsing history sniffing ( they can get the length of the history, I think, though).

How can the browser be secure (If you are browser's vendor)?

- First, it can chose not to support certain capabilities, period such as reading client's file system arbitrarily.
- Second, restrict some of the features they provide.

You might want to take a look at [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) and certain restrictions that are relaxed that might be helpful.

Comment: I'm not an native english speaker so I might not see where I am talking about communicating between tabs, regarding that you are the second to mention this. But I have the feeling no one reads the "When I go to a different page in the same browser window (tab) I suppose the window object remains the same" text...

Comment: @RonS: If you mean clicking the different webpage URL from the page you are at, the same rule applies. For eg., say you are at www.hello.com and there is a link anchored to www.jello.com and you click the anchor, now everything from your global variables to objects are reset. But if the click results in new iframe, you can communicate between the windows in which case the first window becomes the parent window. Hope this clears some of your misunderstanding.

Comment: ok getting close, the first one, clicking an anchor link (or typing a new address in the address bas and hitting enter). Ok so you say everything is reset (cleared). Ok, thank you :)

Comment: Yes, consider what I answered if the new link was able to know variables from old visited link. You can easily see it would allow much more vulnerability for browser security.

Comment: Of course, unless the new page had the same origin ... now I realised that window.localStorage is almost what I wanted some years ago. It is actually a portion of the window object which works like an instance of window declared for one origin (sessionStorage even more so). If it could only hold something else than strings .. you could put for example jQuery inside it ... well maybe in the future ...